# How do I remotely invoke an xterm on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11

Tags: permissions, linux-networking, sles11, xterm

I need to invoke an xterm on a SLES 11 machine (machine A) from another SLES 11 machine (machine B). Currently it doesn't work. So I decided to test some stuff.

On machine A the following works: `DISPLAY=:0.0 xterm`
However this doesn't: `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 xterm`

I'm working on the assumption that if the latter doesn't work then a remote connection won't either.

To me it looks like a permissions issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the other answers. My problem was due to a setting in YaST > Security and Users > Local Security callded 'Disable remote access to the X server'. Enabling this, configuring/disabling the firewall and running `xhost +` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Hey, it seems that Rosco should get the points for answering your question, not you.

Comment: Hey djangofan. I didn't give Rosco the accepted answer because his suggestion, although helpful, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @djangofan, note that you do not get any points when you mark your own answer as the one that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the X server on machine B is configured to accept the connection from machine A ? ("xhost +" and firewall off)

btw on my machine with default settings, therer is no "localhost" keyword, just the 1st line just like your mentioned it.

Comment: The firewall is off and xhost + has been run but still no joy. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ssh with X11 forwarding? It's the easiest and most secure variant these days.

`ssh -X username@hostname`

Comment: This is pretty neat but unfortunately I am working with an existing application that can't be modified to use this solution (for now at least). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @James, you should not have to change anything in your application for it to work through an SSH tunnel. The only thing your application has to do is respect the `$DISPLAY` variable.